# Why is my sendEmails function doing nothing?

Tags: flutter

I followed a tutorial on youtube about how to send an email from my flutter app and I think I did all of it right, but for some reason it doesn't work and I don't know why. I press the button and I do not receive the email. I paste the code below, maybe I missed something.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HW3MZ_tsdo

This is the link to the tutorial if anyone wants it.

```
final myController = TextEditingController();
  final myController2 = TextEditingController();

  Future sendEmail({
  required String name,
  required String message,
}) async {
    const serviceId = 'service_u0es4hc';
    const templateId = 'template_c0g3vmb';
    const userId = 'z2swDcLIPp9H0pa6e';

    final url = Uri.parse('https://api.emailjs.com/api/v1.0/email/send');
    final response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: {
        'origin': 'http://localhost',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        'service_id': serviceId,
        'template_id': templateId,
        'user_id': userId,
        'template_params': {
          'user_name': myController,
          'user_message': myController2,
        }
      }),
    );
}
```

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        showDialog<String>(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.teal[50],
                              title: const Text('Add your sentence!', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),),
                              content: SizedBox(
                                  height: 210,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      const Text('Write here a sentence in your own language and it might be included in the game. Your name is optionally.', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                                      Container(height: 20),
                                      TextField(
                                        cursorColor: Colors.teal,
                                        controller: myController,
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                          hintText: 'Enter your name',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(height: 10),
                                      TextField(
                                        cursorColor: Colors.teal,
                                        controller: myController2,
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                          hintText: 'Enter a sentence',
                                        ),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                              ),
                              elevation: 24,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                              actions: <Widget>[
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    sendEmail(message: myController2.toString() , name: myController.toString());
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                        );
                        myController2.clear();
                        myController.clear();
                      },
                      child: const Text('Add sentences!', textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
                  ),
```

All the id's are correct, I checked like 5 times.

Comment: What is the response from the server?

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by that? On the server it shows that no email has been sent.

Comment: @OzanTaskiran means (probably) what you have in "final response"